# python spreading subprocess.call on multiple CPU cores

Tags: python, subprocess, cpu-usage, multiprocess

I have a python code that uses the subprocess package to run in shell:

```
subprocess.call(mycode.py, shell=inshell)
```

When I execute the top command I see that I am only using ~30% or less of CPU. 
I realize some commands may be using disk and not cpu therefore I was timing the speed. 
The speed running this on a linux system seems slower than a mac 2 core system.

How do I parallelize this with threading or multiprocessing package so that I can use multiple CPU cores on said linux system?

Comment: Do you want to use multiple threads or processes so that you can execute the code in `mycode.py` multiple times? Or do you want to execute `mycode.py` only once and make it go faster by parallelizing the work?

Comment: Yes, I want to execute mycode.py only once but make it go faster by parallelizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little change to FMc's answer,

```
work_items = [(1, 'A', True), (2, 'X', False), (3, 'B', False)]
def worker(tup):
 for i in range(5000000):
     print(work_items)
 return

pool = Pool(processes = 8)
start = time.time()
work_results = pool.map(worker, work_items)
end = time.time()
print(end-start)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The code above takes 53.60 seconds. The trick below however, takes 27.34 seconds.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import functools
import time

work_items = [(1, 'A', True), (2, 'X', False), (3, 'B', False)]

def worker(tup):
    for i in range(5000000):
        print(work_items)
    return

def parallel_attribute(worker):
    def easy_parallelize(worker, work_items):
        pool = Pool(processes = 8)
        work_results = pool.map(worker, work_items)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
    from functools import partial 
    return partial(easy_parallelize, worker)

start = time.time()
worker.parallel = parallel_attribute(worker(work_items))
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Two comments: 
1) I didn't see much of a difference with using multiprocessing dummy
2) Using Python's partial function (scope with nesting) works like a wonderful wrapper that reduces the computation time by 1/2. Reference: https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/simple-python-parallelism/121

Also, Thank you FMc!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `worker.parallel = parallel_attribute(worker)` then `worker.parallel(work_items)`?

Answer (score 3):

To parallelize the work done in `mycode.py`, you need to organize the code so that it fits into this basic pattern:

```
# Import the kind of pool you want to use (processes or threads).
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

# Collect work items as an iterable of single values (eg tuples, 
# dicts, or objects). If you can't hold all items in memory,
# define a function that yields work items instead.
work_items = [
    (1, 'A', True),
    (2, 'X', False),
    ...
]

# Define a callable to do the work. It should take one work item.
def worker(tup):
    # Do the work.
    ...

    # Return any results.
    ...

# Create a ThreadPool (or a process Pool) of desired size.
# What size? Experiment. Slowly increase until it stops helping.
pool = ThreadPool(4)

# Do work and collect results.
# Or use pool.imap() or pool.imap_unordered().
work_results = pool.map(worker, work_items)

# Wrap up.
pool.close()
pool.join()

---------------------

# Or, in Python 3.3+ you can do it like this, skipping the wrap-up code.
with ThreadPool(4) as pool:
    work_results = pool.map(worker, work_items)
```

Comment: The different use-cases for process pools and thread pools are worth mentioning here, given the effects of CPython's GIL on threading.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can create first a thread, then pass to it the function you want to parallelize. Inside the function you have the subprocess.

```
import threading
import subprocess

def worker():
    """thread worker function"""
    print 'Worker'
    subprocess.call(mycode.py, shell=inshell)
    return

threads = []
for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

Comment: Thank you, just wondering: when you specify the number of iterations as 5, how does one determine what the optimum number would be? what determines how many threads will be spreading the subprocess.call function?

Comment: Well, there is no rule that depends on the cpu usage. I will try first with 3 threads as you say you are using ~30% of cpu.