# How to run python script for multiple input on multiple cores at the same time?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have 28 input files and 28 available CPUs. I wrote a python script which uses subprocess to parse input files with QualityAnalysisMain_v2.py. Right now it works fine on one CPU. What I would like to do is to run in pararell each input file on one CPU - 28 runs at the same time.

I have tried approach here: [python spreading subprocess.call on multiple CPU cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41626089/python-spreading-subprocess-call-on-multiple-cpu-cores)

especially this code:

```
import threading
import subprocess

def worker():
    """thread worker function"""
    print 'Worker'
    subprocess.call(mycode.py, shell=inshell)
    return

threads = []
for i in range(5):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

here:

```
for pliki in os.listdir(input_data):
    nazwa = pliki.split(".")[0]
    subprocess.call("mkdir " + output_data + nazwa, shell=True)

def SubprocessFiles():
    for pliki in os.listdir(input_data):
        print("python QualityAnalysisMain_v2.py " + input_data + pliki)
        subprocess.call("python QualityAnalysisMain_v2.py " + input_data + pliki, shell = True)
        return

threads = []
for i in range(28):
    t = threading.Thread(target=SubprocessFiles)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

But it ended up with parsing first input 28 times...

Here is my code  - script is running for each file in input directory but on one CPU:

```
for pliki in os.listdir(input_data):
    nazwa = pliki.split(".")[0]
    print("python QualityAnalysisMain_v2.py " + input_data + pliki)
    subprocess.call("mkdir " + output_data + nazwa, shell = True)
    subprocess.call("python QualityAnalysisMain_v2.py " + input_data + pliki, shell = True)
```

Many thanks for any suggestions.

best, 
Agata

Comment: If you do not show how you pass the files to process to the workers, we cannot guess what is wrong...

Comment: Please, see the updated post. Best!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the same list to all the threads, so all start at the beginning of the list. You should instead pass a singlefile name to each of them:

```
def SubprocessFiles(pliki):
        print("python QualityAnalysisMain_v2.py " + input_data + pliki)
        subprocess.call("python QualityAnalysisMain_v2.py " + input_data + pliki, shell = True)
        return

threads = []
for i, pliki in enumerate(os.listdir(input_data)):
    t = threading.Thread(target=SubprocessFiles, args=[pliki])
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

Comment: @Agata: please do not forget to accept the answer to show future readers that you no longer need help with this question.