# Using multithreading - worker not defined when function present

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a bit of a long script, so a minimum viable example may not be easily possible.

I'm trying to follow some previous [SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41626089/python-spreading-subprocess-call-on-multiple-cpu-cores) about threading - I wish to execute an exe dozens of times and to use as many CPU cores as possible. Early days here.

First I'm defining a list with elements that are dynamically populated

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

work_items = []
```

Then I'm defining a function, at the same indent level as all my other working functions:

```
#To help with executing my exe in Parallel
    def worker(tup):
        subprocess.call(tup)
```

Then, finally, inside the function that will call this function:

```
#Execute jobs
        start = time.time()
        with ThreadPool(4) as pool:
            work_results = pool.map(worker, work_items)
        end = time.time()
        print(end - start)
```

The line that is causing me grief is `work_results = pool.map(worker, work_items)`. My linter in VSCode, and the python shell when I attempt to test both return that `worker is not defined`. My understanding is that the function should be in scope, and it is defined.

Is there something here that stands out as an issue as to why it would be reporting that worker is an undefined function?

Comment: `to use as many CPU cores as possible` with cpython and threading not possible due to GIL

Comment: @Epsi95: Given the thread is just launching an external process, it'll work fine; the GIL prevents CPU bound Python level code from executing simultaneously, but in this case, all the workers just launch a subprocess and block waiting for it to finish (and while blocked, they release the GIL).

Comment: I don't think this is answerable. If your assertions about scope are correct, then this code should work. But all we have are your assertions; you removed all the code from context. We can't verify the scope is correct without a [MCVE].

Comment: Yes that is true if the individual program utilizes all the cores, but if the OP has a notion that he/she can use all the CPU cores using multithreading, that needs to be pointed out.

Comment: Thanks ShadowRanger. I normally try pretty hard to provide a MRE, this time is not so easy. I appreciate the comment son scope. My thoughts were it seemed to look ok.

Comment: @Epsi95: The OP is very clear they're doing this to execute a given exe in parallel. Even if each exe only uses a single core, Python thread pools could launch enough of them to saturate all the cores. The GIL is (effectively) irrelevant when you're not running CPU bound Python code.

Comment: Just to add to ShadowRangers point - the Python code here is not CPU bound, any hard work has already been done, memory released, files written out. Now it's about handing off the results to a dedicated program that does the next step, but can only handle one set of input files at a time. The idea is to get many copies of that program to fire at once and to share the load across cores since the program itself is fairly light weight but can be intermittently data processing intensive.

Comment: Okay understood, it is like just starting an external program. @ShadowRanger thanks for the clarification but when you said `The GIL is (effectively) irrelevant when you're not running CPU bound Python code` that is true, but if I have 4 cores, then I can start for ex: 32 I/O bound threads in 4 cores making it 4*32, but If I simply use multithreading I can't use the remaining 3 cores.

Comment: As it turned out, there was in fact a scope issue. For whatever reason all my other functions were working when placed inside a class, except this one (worker). Placing it outside the main class within which the rest of the code is running fixed the issue. On to the next battle - why it seems that subprocess.call isn't executing the target program as desired. Some days are just uphill all day, heh.